# Excel 2010 macro to get and set the equivalence in another cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm trying to make a macro or any sort of data validation  in excel 2010 to set a cell value based on the selection equivalence of another cell

Exemple let's say I have 2 columns filled like this

A1----------B2

---

1  ---------- I

---

2 ----------  II

---

3  ---------- III

---

4  ---------- IV

---

5  ----------    V

---

What I would like to do  is to configure another columns (let's take D1 as an example ) If I select number "3" in any row ,  I want "III" To be set in the same row in columns E1 and vice versa if I select IV in any row of E1 I want the current row in D1 to be set automatically to "4"

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: You should be able to do this by trapping the Change event on the worksheet.  Plenty of posts here on SO which cover doing that.

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks Tim for the hint I will check

Comment: I would appreciate  a link if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the code module for the worksheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim v, nv, f As Range, c As Range, d As Range

    'only considering single-cell updates here...
    Set c = Target.Cells(1)

    'check we're in Col D or Col E
    If Not Intersect(c, Me.Range("D:E")) Is Nothing Then

        v = c.Value     'new value to look up
        nv = ""         'default "matching value" is empty...

        'The cell to be updated: offset to the left or to the right
        '  from the one which was just updated
        Set d = c.Offset(0, IIf(c.Column = 4, 1, -1))
        Set f = Nothing

        If c.Column = 4 Then
            Set f = Me.Range("A1:A10").Find(v, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
            If Not f Is Nothing Then
                nv = f.Offset(0, 1).Value
            End If
        Else 'column=5...
            Set f = Me.Range("B1:B10").Find(v, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
            If Not f Is Nothing Then
                nv = f.Offset(0, -1).Value
            End If
        End If

        'Turn off events to prevent re-triggering this method
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        'update the other cell....
        d.Value = nv  

        'Re-enable events: must do this! 
        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If
End Sub
```

EDIT:  here's a more generic approach which can cover any number of columns

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const LOOKUP_RANGE As String = "A1:C5" 'Lookup table
    Const INPUT_RANGE As String = "D:F"    'Where you want to respond to input
                                           ' should be same # of cols as lookup range

    Dim v, c As Range, d As Range, rw As Range, colNum As Long, m

    Set c = Target.Cells(1) 'only considering single-cell updates here...

    'check we're in the "input" range
    If Not Intersect(c, Me.Range(INPUT_RANGE)) Is Nothing Then

        'This is the range to be updated
        Set rw = Application.Intersect(c.EntireRow, Me.Range(INPUT_RANGE))
        'which column to check?
        colNum = (c.Column - rw.Cells(1).Column) + 1

        v = c.Value     'new value to look up

        'see if we can find the just-entered value in the lookup range
        m = Application.Match(v, Me.Range(LOOKUP_RANGE).Columns(colNum), 0)

        'Turn off events to prevent re-triggering this method
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        If Not IsError(m) Then
            rw.Value = Me.Range(LOOKUP_RANGE).Rows(m).Value
        Else
            rw.ClearContents 'no match: clear the row
            c.Value = v 'and restore the entered value
        End If

        'Re-enable events: must do this!
        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello and thank you so much @Tim , I will mark this as resolved because it does what I ask , but let's say I want to affect  a third column the Range F with the value of range C , how should I Modify ?

Comment: Let's say In the colons C we have the letters A,B,C,D,E,F,G so whenever I add a number in colons  D or E or F ( ex: I added the number 3 in D , the code you provided witch help a lot will add III in the proper row of E , but If I want also the code to add the letter C in the current row of F) How can I modify the code to do that? should I open a new thread providing what I tried? thanks a lot so far

Comment: Working PERFECTLY ! Thanks Tim  !!

Comment: forgive me if Im asking too much , but if the lookup range are in another sheet , will it be as simple as writing Const LOOKUP_RANGE As String = "Sheet2!A:Sheet2!C" ? Or a whole code modification should be done?